# ExpoBarCodeScannerModule.scanFromURLAsync thrown an error

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to make a scanner in React Native that takes an image file, scans it and returns data that contains in barcode. I'm using a [BarCodeScanner](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/) extension from Expo SDK. 
It throws an error when I'm trying to use it.
Error looks like:

```
An exception was thrown while calling `ExpoBarCodeScannerModule.scanFromURLAsync` with arguments `(
    1,
        (
        "org.iso.QRCode"
    )
)`: -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe17787ebcc27c1d0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:104:55 in <unknown>
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:414:4 in __invokeCallback
- ... 4 more stack frames from framework internals
```

My code where I'm trying to use extension method:

```
file = require('./assets/image.jpg');
componentDidMount(){
   BarCodeScanner.scanFromURLAsync(this. file).then(data => {
       console.log(data)
     }).catch(err => {
       console.log(err)
     })
}
```

Do you have any thoughts what does it mean?

Comment: It means that the BarCodeScanner does not accept a .jpg file

Comment: You should provide a url to the BarCodeScanner. Check out this [example](https://snack.expo.io/@documentation/barcodescanner-example?platform=ios).

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late, but for anyone with simmilar problem. You can use expo ImagePicker package to select image. It will return array of objects. One of the parameters of the object is URI of the image that can be used as an input to BarCodeScanner.scanFromURLAsync method.

```js
      const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          allowsEditing: false,
          quality: 1,
        });
    
        if (!result.canceled) {
          let decodedBarcodeImage = await BarCodeScanner.scanFromURLAsync(result.assets[0].uri);
          // Handle result data
          console.log(decodedBarcodeImage);
        } else {
          // Handle canceled result
          console.log('You did not select any image.');
        }
      };
```

Comment: what if image does not contain QR code and you try scan it?

Comment: Hi, in the documentation for the Expo BarCodeScanner scanFromURLAsync method return is stated:  "@return A possibly empty array of objects of the BarCodeScannerResult shape, where the type refers to the bar code type that was scanned and the data is the information encoded in the bar code." This means that it will return an array of objects, where each object represents a decoded barcode. If there is 1 barcode, the array will have size 1. If there are multiple barcodes, there will be multiple objects in the array. If there is no barcode, the array will be empty.

Comment: Hey, app is crashing before return anything

Comment: This is just a function, not a whole app. In my app where I tested this function it worked just fine. If your app is crashing, check the error log. Maybe you just need to install the Expo ImagePicker library. If it continues to crash and you can't find out why, create a separate question on stackoverflow with the problematic code.